# É possível deixar rodando um embed do Youtube em background no iOS?

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, iphone, youtube, ionic

Estou fazendo um projeto utilizando Ionic + Cordova e queria saber se é possível no iPhone deixar um vídeo do Youtube rodando em background ao bloquear a tela. Por padrão os dispositivos com iOS pausam o vídeo ao entrar em background.

Comment: Amigo, já fiz tantas pesquisas sobre isso e infelizmente até hoje não conseguir encontrar uma alternativa. Já tentei de tudo mas é realmente complexo. No seu caso ainda deve ser mais complicado ainda, já que o vídeo é embed.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível.

O motivo é que, o iOS não permite que você execute video, ou qualquer outra coisa relacionada a interface, enquanto seu app está em background.

O iOS permite que você execute faixas de audio em background sem problemas, porém, como você está engessado no YouTube, isso também não vai dar certo, já que o YT proíbe a extração do audio para executa-lo separado do video.